# Mongoose Schema - create method add an unexpected value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a strange problem with Mongoose. I have Schema called Contest:

```
module.exports = {
 attributes: {
   duels: [duelSchema],
   author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
   name: String,
   description: String,
   media: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: {background: null, shareImage: null}
};
```

When I want to edit `media` property in existing record, I do it in this way:

```
contest.media['shareImage'] = imageObject;
contest.markModified('media');
contest.save();
```

After that existing record is updated. But then after that I try to add new record in other place in service using this code:

```
Contest.create({
  author: author,
  name: 'Contest title',
  description: ''
});
```

the new contest record have `media` property the same as record updated before.

I don't have idea why Mongoose adds value to `media` field when i don't pass it to method `create`

Comment: Are you perhaps reusing the `contest` variable? Showing more code would help.

Comment: I update existing record in other controller method, and after that I create new one in next controller method, so this is not case when I reusing the same `contest` variable

Comment: You need to show some more code. How define the schema? Are you sure you didn't set image in a hook?